# Delete same object from different pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a User model and a Company model. Company `has_many :users` and User `belongs_to :company`

In 2 different pages, I list the users. One page is all users, and the other page is a company profile page which has users belongs to that company.

When I delete a common user, `destroy` method is called naturally and after delete its `redirect_to` somewhere. But I want to stay which page I am.

How can I do that?

Comment: can you post your destroy method code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
redirect_to :back
```

in your destroy action.